# Changing character between two strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How can i change the character after "#overlay/" and before "/" after that first one?

```
var x = "www.foo.com/#overlay/2/";
x.replace(/#overlay\/([^]*)\//, "1"); // i'm expecting: www.foo.com/#overlay/1/
```

I'm using this code, but no success. I don't understand that much from regex.

I've searched some questions but without success.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a regular expression here. You can just use `.split()`.

```
var url, newUrl, peices;

url = 'www.foo.com/#overlay/2/';

// Split the string apart by / 
peices = url.split('/');

// Changing the 3 element in the array to 1, it was originally 2.
peices[2] = 1;

// Let's put it back together...
newUrl = peices.join('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making 3 mistakes :

- you're replacing too much
- you don't use the returned value. `replace` doesn't change the passed string (strings are immutable) but returns a new one
- you forgot to precise in your capturing group when to stop (in fact it doesn't even have to be a capturing group)

You can do this :

```
x = x.replace(/(#overlay\/)[^\/]*\//, "$11/");
```

`$1` here refers to the first captured group, so that you don't have to type it in the replacement string.

For example it changes

```
"www.foo.com/#overlay/2/rw/we/2345"
```

into

```
"www.foo.com/#overlay/1/rw/we/2345"
```

Comment: Your code is fine, but is cutting everything after the `#overlay/n/`

so if the link is: `...#overlay/2/rw/we/2345` it returns `#overlay/1/`, i just want to change the character after `#overlay/` and before the next `/`, everything else remains the same

Comment: @CBroe, it's the first line of my question!

Comment: If the part to replace is always numeric, then `replace(/#overlay\/([0-9]+)\//, "1/")` should work.